# Unknown Reason For Error 'Undefined Index'

Tags: php

I have defined the index yet I still receive the error message 'undefined index email'
Here is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$email = $_POST['email'];
}
$securityq = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT securityq FROM admin WHERE email = '$_POST[email]'");
?>
```

Can anyone see the problem here?

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intranet\passwordreset.php on line 28

Comment: where is your form and at which line you get error???

Comment: check your field has name `email` in form.

Comment: write your full error message, is it "undefined index email" ?

Comment: yes, name of field in form is 'email' and the error is on the line I posted $securityq = ......

Comment: Execute the query inside the `if` conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql in your original code relied upon the submission of the form - if there was no POST there was no variable to use in the sql.

```
$email = isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
if( $email ) {
    $sql="SELECT `securityq` FROM `admin` WHERE `email` = '{$email}';";
    $securityq = mysqli_query( $db, $sql );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the code like this.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    }
    $securityq = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT securityq FROM admin WHERE email = '{$email}'");
    ?>
```